# Polygon Data for European countries

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for polygon data for the countries.

I have found a great example at

http://www.zonums.com/gmaps/colorit2.php

but it contains only regions/provences data of a county. But I am looking for countries data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some basic layers of countries in ArcGIS example files but I don't know about their license... Also you can try http://openstreetmap.org/ or http://opencyclemap.org/ to find some separate layer of country boundaries...

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find pretty good sources of most (or even all) world countries: [countries-shapes](http://www.gadm.org/country)

Answer (score 0):

When I was searching for the same I found this one matching my needs [world_borders](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)